# Complex Number Based Problem:How to prove the following?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> If
>   $$\frac{2}{w}=\frac{1}{a+w}+\frac{1}{b+w}+\frac{1}{c+w}+\frac{1}{d+w}$$
>   $$\frac{2}{w^2}=\frac{1}{a+w^2}+\frac{1}{b+w^2}+\frac{1}{c+w^2}+\frac{1}{d+w^2}$$
>
> How to prove the following?
>
> $$(a){Σabc}=2$$ and  $$(b){Σa}=2Πa$$

Can someone give me a hint atleast so that I can begin with.I tried summing up the fractions but its becoming too complicated.Please help.

Σ stands for summation.

Π stands for product.

$w$ is complex cube root of unity.

$a,b,c,d$ are all real.

Comment: DOWNVOTER.Please tell me how I may improve the question.Please.

Comment: Didn't downvote but:

Could you clarify what the indices of the sum and product are? Also the proper sum notation in LaTex is "\sum_{i=1}^n$.

Comment: @AlexR. ${Σabc}=2$ implies $abc+abd+acd+...(6 terms)=2$ and part (b) is $(a+b+c)=2abc$.

Comment: What happened to $d$?

Comment: Sorry I meant (a+b+c+d)=2abcd @AlexR. (sleepiness is taking a toll on me :-P...pardon that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{a+x}+\frac{1}{b+x}+\frac{1}{c+x}+\frac{1}{d+x}-\frac{2}{x}$

Putting $f(x)=0$ we get $2x^4+Σax^3-Σabcx-2abcd=0$

Let the roots be $w,w^2,\gamma,\delta$

Using Viete's formulae the following results may be obtained.

$\gamma+\delta=1-Σa/2$ -----(1)

$-\gamma\delta+\gamma+\delta=Σabc/2$------(2)

$\gamma\delta=-abcd$--------(3)

$1+\gamma\delta=\gamma+\delta$------(4)

Eliminating $\gamma,\delta$ the required results may be obtained.

Moreover $x=1$ is also found to be satisfying $f(x)=0$.